# How to configure Conemu to highlight icon in taskbar during long time operation that is not providing time to finish?

Tags: command-line, conemu

I'm developer and using console for builds. build operation in console is taking much time so I'm minimizing console and doing some other tasks. But time to time i have to look into console to see if build is finished already.

So idea is configure Conemu to highlight button on taskbar during this operation like this is doing some programs.

is it possible to do in Conemu?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GuiMacro](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/GuiMacro) to script that behavior.

To start highlighting

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro Progress 3
```

To stop highlighting

```
ConEmuC -GuiMacro Progress 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but as i see GuiMacro is triggered by user but in my case those macro should be executed before start and after finish process

Comment: And what is the restriction to "execute before start and after finish"?

Comment: I meant "how to automatically execute `ConEmuC -GuiMacro Progress 3` once some program is run and execute `ConEmuC -GuiMacro Progress 0` once program is finished"

Comment: Of course it is not possible. Create small batch/sh/etc script which will do that and run your apps with it.

Comment: Can you treat this as feature request? :)
Currently ConEmu is already showing progress on task bar if running program informs about progress. But it would be great if it will blink (Firefox doing this once it is loading file of unknown size) once program is running.

Comment: Firefox always knows what it is doing. ConEmu does **not** know what console applications are doing at the moment. When progress is printed in the console title or in the current line - conclusion is simple. But in your case - the logic is too undetermined.